# SignalR : Microsoft JScript Runtime Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have just made a new web app using ASP.NET MVC 4 and SignalR, then I tested my App on 4 different machines all running VS2012 in Windows7 x64 and Windows 8 and IE 9 and 10. In two machines works OK but in the other 2 I'm getting the following error after a while:

```
Unhandled exception at line 1, column 9 in __http://localhost:4004/signalr?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=739e3932-48f1-4e1d-8ef2-ea32e15d2929&connectionData=[{"name":"notificationhub"}]&messageId=B,77|C,0|D,0|E,0&tid=9&frameId=1

0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'r' is undefined
```

As a curiosity those two machines also have VS2010 installed and originally they did not had Update 1 for VS2012 installed, now I installed Update 1 on both machines and still have the errors.

Any ideas?

Both failing machines have w7 x64 and the two working have w7 x64 in one and the other has w8 x64

**EDIT:**
I have IE9 on both failing computers and IE10 and 9 on the OK computers, also tested Google Chrome 20 on one of the failing machines and the problem disappeared, so, it seems to be browser-related. So, the question is:
Why I have one ie9 that works ok and another that doesn´t?

Comment: The javascript is minified, so you can not see whats going wrong with that only. You need to use the full version of the javascript, also the browser is the one that have the issue, not the machine. Maybe some script is not loaded or not run.

Comment: @Aristos I have changed jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.min.js to jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js and the problem disapeared, so: it could be possible that the min version is different to the other version?

Comment: Its very possible and happens the minified code to create code that is not working in some cases. You can use some custom minified (like I do) to minified the javascript code and make sure that works, not only on IE, but also on other browsers. I use ms ajax minified.

Comment: @Aristos Well I have included jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js in a bundle and the problem started again... ufff!!! Any ideas other than using the un-minified file?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not have experience in that particular library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SignalR 1.0.0-rc2?

It looks like the forever frame preamble is not being sent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>SignalR Forever Frame Transport Stream</title>
<script>
    var $ = window.parent.jQuery,
        ff = $ ? $.signalR.transports.foreverFrame : null,
        c =  ff ? ff.getConnection('1') : null,
        r = ff ? ff.receive : function() {};
        ff ? ff.started(c) : '';</script></head><body>
```

Whithout this preamble, when a message is sent through the forever frame, you will get an `'r' is undefined` error:

```
<script>r(c, {"json": "message"});</script>
```

It shouldn't be possible to receive a message through forever frame without receiving a preamble, so that's why I ask which versioin of SignalR you are using.

IE10 is likely using the WebSockets transport and non IE browsers are likely using [Sever-sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) which would explain why these browsers work correctly.

**EDIT:** As jcgalveza comments below, since the error seems to be specific to the `foreverFrame` transport, it can be selectively disabled when starting the connection like so:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] }) //...
```

This is safe because all browsers supported by SignalR support long polling. The three transports listed above are all the transports currently supported by SignalR except for, of course, `foreverFrame`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ver 1.0.0-rc2, Ok about other browser but still not understand why when I changed to the non-minified version it started to work ok, also doesn't explain why on some computers works ok and in others don´t. The common thing on the two "not-working" computers in that they have VS2010 installed side-by-side with VS2012. Now I included the jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js in a Bundle and the problem started again. Any sugestions to solve this?

Comment: I found an old bug (that is supposed to be solved) that, as a workaround, recomend this: $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] }); instead of $.connection.hub.start();. Will all browsers work ok if I do that?

Comment: Yes. All browsers can fall back to the longPolling transport, so you should be OK. The only issue is that IE <= 9 will have to use longPolling which doesn't perform quite as well as foreverFrame.

Comment: Ok thanks. Any ideas on why when I use the unminified version it works find and when I minifiy that same version on a bundle then it starts failing again? Please pos your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: I don't know why minification would cause this issue. I updated my answer to include your eventual solution.

Comment: I have filed a bug on git hub, I hope this issue with ie9 will be solved soon. Thanks